# Error creating Membership with roles with aspnet.regsql.exe

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have an asp.net app, I am using vs 2010, and I connect to sql server express 2008 r2 using windows authentication.   I can connect to my database and crud my data through my app just fine.

I am trying to implement Membership with roles on my website

When I run the aspnet.regsql.exe utility, I get the following error message:
Setup failed.

Exception:
Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

---

### Details of failure

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install)
   at System.Web.Management.ConfirmPanel.Execute()

Also, I am unable to use the ASP.NET Website Adimistration Tool. When I click on the Security tab I receive the following error:

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

So, I click on the 'Choose Data Store' button as instructed, which allows me to select a a Provider. The provider is named 'AspNetSqlProvider', it has a Test link beside it. I click on Test and receive the following message:
Successfully established a connection to the database.

Successfully established a connection to the database.   this works, but the problems still exists, and the previous errors occur when i repeat the steps i have already discussed.

Does anybody know whats causing this, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to connect to the SQL Server, then either your connection string has an error, or you do not have SQL Server enabled for mixed mode authentication.

Comment: The database is setup for mixed mode.  What connection is it looking for? i have setup the ApplicationServices connection.  my application can connect to and update the database.  Is there a specific connection that i need to add to my web.config?

Comment: I did track down the issue to the problem.  This came down to being a permission problem.  The mdf had permission for the admin user, but I was logged in as a different user.  I changed the permissions to allow access to an existing aspnet.mdf, and changed the web.config to point to the db.  The configuration was able to pick up the database, and i could now access the database.  Not exactly a slick solution